# Jquery how to split blur and enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split blur and enter key functions. So I mean that I want jquery to do another function on blur and another on enter key. If enter key was clicked then blur mustn't work, so blur function mustn't execute. This is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#comment_textarea").on("keypress blur", function(e) {

        if(e.type == "keypress" & e.which == 13){
            alert("type: "+e.type+"||which: "+e.which);
        }
        else if(e.type != "keypress" ){
            alert("type: "+e.type+"||which: "+e.keycode);
        }
    });
})
```

This code alerts two times. First is blur and second is enter click. Have anyone got any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to debug blur events with `alert()`, because `alert()` changes the focus. Use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you show an alert the textarea isn't focused anymore, the blur event will be triggered then.

Comment: So that is mistake. Thanks I will try not to alert but to do a function and I will see if it will do the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $("#comment_textarea").on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // do your Enter key stuff
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $("#comment_textarea").on("blur", function (e) {
        // handle the blur
    });
});
```

Trying to double up probably isn't the best way.

Comment: I have tryed it but it was doing the same. Problem was what @Hatsjoem said. Thank you for reply